# CSS to make an iframe take the rest of the height of the page?

Tags: html, css, xhtml, iframe

If I have something like this:

```
<p>Element<p>
<iframe src = "otherPage.html" style = "width:100%;height:100%">
</iframe>
```

The iframe runs off the page. For various reasons, I can't specify an absolute height. What is the proper CSS way to make an element use the remaining height of its container element? A quick google search claimed this impossible, but certainly there's a workaround. The inner iframe here has a gradient, which due to IE's inability to display clear iframe backgrounds, must just take up the rest of the page.

Thoughts?

Comment: I would suggest using alternative methods to include external content on your page. IFrames are not indexed by search engines as far as I know, and some users might even have frames disabled alltogether..

Comment: I'd suggest a `<table>` tag. There's no clean way to do this in CSS, and a javascript solution is.. Kind of like trying to squash a bug with a sledgehammer.

Comment: @Eirik: I would, but Linux is broken and tends to crash firefox when my page loads, but only if SELinux or similar firewall policies are enabled. Using an iframe to emulate the ajax calls I was making before, I get no crashing.

Comment: @Duroth: How would you use a table tag for this? I don't see the 1:1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So many repeats of this question :)

You can achieve this using javascript:

This script was taken from [Dynamic Drive](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/) and altered:
(just rememebr to specify
 `var iframeids = ["Whatever frame id's you want to auto-resize seperated by ,"]`

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    /***********************************************
    * IFrame SSI script II- © Dynamic Drive DHTML code library (http://www.dynamicdrive.com)
    * Visit DynamicDrive.com for hundreds of original DHTML scripts
    * This notice must stay intact for legal use
    ***********************************************/

    //Input the IDs of the IFRAMES you wish to dynamically resize to match its content height:
    //Separate each ID with a comma. Examples: ["myframe1", "myframe2"] or ["myframe"] or [] for none:
    var iframeids = ["contentFrame"]

    //Should script hide iframe from browsers that don't support this script (non IE5+/NS6+ browsers. Recommended):
    var iframehide = "no"

    var getFFVersion = navigator.userAgent.substring(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox")).split("/")[1]
    var FFextraHeight = parseFloat(getFFVersion) >= 0.1 ? 16 : 0 //extra height in px to add to iframe in FireFox 1.0+ browsers

    function resizeCaller() {
        var dyniframe = new Array()
        for (i = 0; i < iframeids.length; i++) {
            if (document.getElementById)
                resizeIframe(iframeids[i])
            //reveal iframe for lower end browsers? (see var above):
            if ((document.all || document.getElementById) && iframehide == "no") {
                var tempobj = document.all ? document.all[iframeids[i]] : document.getElementById(iframeids[i])
                tempobj.style.display = "block"
            }
        }
    }

    function resizeIframe(frameid) {
        var currentfr = document.getElementById(frameid)
        if (currentfr && !window.opera) {
            currentfr.style.display = "block"
            if (currentfr.contentDocument && currentfr.contentDocument.body.offsetHeight) //ns6 syntax
                currentfr.height = currentfr.contentDocument.body.offsetHeight + FFextraHeight;
            else if (currentfr.contentDocument && currentfr.contentDocument.documentElement.offsetHeight) //ns6 syntax
                currentfr.height = currentfr.contentDocument.documentElement.offsetHeight + FFextraHeight;
            else if (currentfr.Document && currentfr.Document.body.scrollHeight) //ie5+ syntax
                currentfr.height = currentfr.Document.body.scrollHeight;
            else if (currentfr.Document && currentfr.Document.documentElement.scrollHeight) //ie5+ syntax
                currentfr.height = currentfr.Document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
            if (currentfr.addEventListener)
                currentfr.addEventListener("load", readjustIframe, false)
            else if (currentfr.attachEvent) {
                currentfr.detachEvent("onload", readjustIframe) // Bug fix line
                currentfr.attachEvent("onload", readjustIframe)
            }
        }
    }

    function readjustIframe(loadevt) {
        var crossevt = (window.event) ? event : loadevt
        var iframeroot = (crossevt.currentTarget) ? crossevt.currentTarget : crossevt.srcElement
        if (iframeroot)
            resizeIframe(iframeroot.id);
    }

    function loadintoIframe(iframeid, url) {
        if (document.getElementById)
            document.getElementById(iframeid).src = url
    }

    if (window.addEventListener)
        window.addEventListener("load", resizeCaller, false)
    else if (window.attachEvent)
        window.attachEvent("onload", resizeCaller)
    else
        window.onload = resizeCaller

</script>
```

[link text](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/)

Comment: This is the worst solution ever.

Comment: yeah agreed! However I dont think its possible to do it in CSS and have it cross-browser compatible :/

Comment: ...yeah. That's why I gave you the accept, but I refuse to upvote! If I could downvote without down-repping, I would!